# Trouble with displaying numbers in labels. Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, label

I am currently enrolled in a visual basic class through my university and I am having trouble with one of the exercises assigned to me. I need to display the cost of an item for a company and I cannot get anything to display in a label.

This is the code

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off

Public Class MainForm

    Private Sub BtnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnCalc.Click

        Dim intCost As Double

        If RadTwin.Checked Then
            intCost = 39.99
        ElseIf RadFull.Checked Then
            intCost = 49.99
        ElseIf RadQueen.Checked Then
            intCost = 49.99
        ElseIf RadKing.Checked Then
            intCost = 69.99
        End If

        lblCost.Text = intCost.ToString("n")
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadTwin_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadTwin.CheckedChanged
        lblCost.Text = String.Empty
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadFull_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadFull.CheckedChanged
        lblCost.Text = String.Empty
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadQueen_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadQueen.CheckedChanged
        lblCost.Text = String.Empty
    End Sub

    Private Sub RadKing_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadKing.CheckedChanged
        lblCost.Text = String.Empty
    End Sub
End Class
```

I need to display the cost of each item in the lblCost when the radio button is chosen. I have worked at getting this to work for hours but I am not knowledgeable enough to know what to do. If anyone has any ideas on how to make this code work I would greatly appreciate it. It is likely something stupid simple that I am missing but I want to learn how to solve this problem if it happens again in the future.

Comment: Firstly, why do you have a `Double` variable named `intCost`? Hungarian Notation is bad enough but incorrect Hungarian Notation is orders of made worse.  When something is intended specifically to indicate type and it actually indicates the wrong type, that's making bad worse.

Comment: The code you have specifically clears the `Label` when you check a `RadioButton` and only displays something when you click `BtnCalc`.  if that's not what you want, you probably ought to write code that does something else.

Comment: I honestly have no idea. I originally had it as dblCost but changed it after reviewing other examples that I have access to. I am not good at this class, something I probably should have said before.

Comment: You need to actually think about what you're doing and do things for a specific reason rather than just copying blindly from the internet.  What's the point of those prefixes?  They are to indicate type.  What type do you think "int" indicates?  Is your variable that type?

Comment: This is the first time I have asked anyone on the internet for help with this class. I have never practiced code before and this is the first class I have ever taken. The class is online and I have no one else that can help me with anything. If I don't understand something I have to resort to other examples in the book in hopes of seeing the mistake I am making and changing it. I understand that int means integer and dbl means double.

Comment: *"I understand that int means integer and dbl means double"*.  Then this won't be an issue in future.  Persoanlly, I hate Hungarian Notation for .NET development.  It had it's place back when data types were few code was written in text editors but it makes little sense when writing VB.NET code in Visual Studio.  Unfortunately, it gets taught to beginners a lot because many who teach VB.NET are still stuck VB6-land themselves. If you are going to use type prefixes though, it only makes sense to use accurate type prefixes.  Otherwise they are worse than no prefixes.

Comment: As for the issue, do you see that you are clearing the `Label` when you check a `RadioButton` and only setting you click the `Button`?  Is that your intention?  Are you saying, without actually saying, that you don't see anything when you click the `Button` too?

Comment: The whole point of the check changed event was to clear the label whenever you click a different radio button. I have removed those lines of code and nothing shows in the label still. If that isn't what you are talking about then I apologize. I have tried changing the double alternative structure into a single alternative and I still cannot get it to work. I apologize for me being so incompetent. I shouldn't have taken this class as it doesn't relate to my major.

Comment: Are you clicking `BtnCalc`? If not then of course nothing is displayed, because the code to display the text is in the `Click` event handler for that `Button`.  If you are clicking that `Button` then I can't see why the appropriate text would not be displayed.  That's where you need to debug your code.  Unfortunately, many classes/courses are criminally negligent when it comes to teaching the essential skill of debugging.  You should set a breakpoint on the line that displays the text and watch as it gets executed.  If you don't know how to debug, you should learn how now.

Comment: I am clicking the button that is related to btnCalc and no matter what I do I cannot get it to display it. I have not learned how to properly debug code as you have suggested above. All that I have been taught to do is troubleshoot issues when I get build errors. Do you know anywhere that could help me learn how to do this properly? Also, thank you for being so patient with someone so incompetent.

Comment: [This](https://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets5p6.html) is just one of any places that can help.  I was already aware of that site but I found that link by searching the web for "vb.net debugging".

Comment: Ok. I appreciate the help with everything. I am going to restart the project and go through everything again. Hopefully I can find what the issue could be.

Comment: It also pays to consider that the `CheckedChanged` event of a `RadioButton` or `Checkbox` is raised whenever the `Checked` property changes, so whenever it is checked OR unchecked.  Often it doesn't matter from the user's perspective but, more often than not, you really ought to be acting only when the control is checked, so you'd need an `If` statement in the event handler.

Comment: Additionally, instead of having 4 identical subs with one handler each, you can have one sub with all handlers. Like this: Private Sub RB_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadTwin.CheckedChanged,  Handles RadFull.CheckedChanged,  Handles RadQueen.CheckedChanged,  Handles RadKing.CheckedChanged

Comment: In your If block add a final `Else lblCost.Text = "Nothing was checked" End If` It might give a clue to what is wrong.

Comment: Do not use Option Infer Off. It forces you to declare everything even if it is pretty clear what type you want to use.